# Axios : send image with FormData on Prestashop API

Tags: node.js, axios, prestashop, form-data

I'm trying to upload on image on the Prestashop API with form-data/axios.
For that, i just need to send a post request with the images joined in an "image" parameter.

I did this simple node.js script (mine is much more complicated but i simplified for here):

```
const FormData = require("form-data");
const fs = require("fs");
const axios = require("axios");

// Read the image file into a buffer
const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync("image.jpg");

// Create a FormData object
const form = new FormData();

// Append the image buffer to the form data
form.append("image", imageBuffer);

// Make an HTTP POST request to the PrestaShop API
axios({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://XXX/api/images/products/15924",
  data: form, // set the request body using the data field
  params: {
    ws_key: "XXX",
  },
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + form.getBoundary(),
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.response.data);
  });
```

But i get this answer:

```
<message><![CDATA[Please set an "image" parameter with image data for value]]></message>
```

I tried a LOT of things. With fs.createReadStream instead of formData, with http instead of axios, with a buffer or a file, etc ... and i alway end with this error.

I would be glad if someone has an idea :-)

Thx !

Comment: Try to add meta info as the third argument for the append method ```form.append( 'my_file', fs.createReadStream('/foo/bar.jpg'), {filename: 'bar.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpeg', knownLength: 19806} );```

Comment: I tried but still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeed!

Two changed were needed:

1. Adding the filename in the append (thanks Dmitriy Mozgovoy for pointing that out in the comment)
2. Adding the size in the headers with `"Content-Length": formData.getLengthSync()`

Without these 2 missing elements, it seems that PHP received an empty `$_FILES` variable.

Final version:

```js
const FormData = require("form-data");
const fs = require("fs");
const axios = require("axios");

// Read the image file into a buffer
const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync("image.jpg");

// Create a FormData object
const form = new FormData();

// Append the image buffer to the form data
form.append("image", imageBuffer, "image.jpg");

// Make an HTTP POST request to the PrestaShop API
axios
  .post("https://example.com/api/images/products/15924", form, {
    params: {
      ws_key: "EXAMPLE",
    },
    headers: {
      ...form.getHeaders(),
      "Content-Length": form.getLengthSync(),
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.response.data);
  });
```